# Posting solr.DFRSimilarityFactory similarity

Tags: solr, similarity

It looks like I'm not able to set solr.DFRSimilarityFactory parameters posting a new field type on managed schemas...

```html
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
  "replace-field-type": {
    "name": "text_dfr",
    "class": "solr.TextField",
    "positionIncrementGap": "100",
    "multiValued": true,
    "similarity": {
      "class": "solr.DFRSimilarityFactory",
      "basicModel": "I(F)",
      "afterEffect": "B",
      "normalization": "H2"
    },
    "indexAnalyzer": {
      "tokenizer": {
        "class": "solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"
      },
      "filters": [{
          "class": "solr.StopFilterFactory", "words": "stopwords.txt", "ignoreCase": "true"
        }, {
          "class": "solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"
        }]
    },
    "queryAnalyzer": {
      "tokenizer": {
        "class": "solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"
      },
      "filters": [
        {
          "class": "solr.StopFilterFactory",
          "words": "stopwords.txt",
          "ignoreCase": "true"
        },
        {
          "class": "solr.SynonymFilterFactory",
          "expand": "true",
          "ignoreCase": "true",
          "synonyms": "synonyms.txt"
        },
        {
          "class": "solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}' http://localhost:8983/solr/questions/schema
```

And response is...

```html
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":207},
  "errors":[{
  ...
      "errorMessages":["Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType\nInvalid basicModel: null\n"]}]}
```

There should be something wrong in my arguments posting. Any hint?